# Using Core Graphics in Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, core-graphics, skspritenode, skshapenode

I am using Sprite Kit. I have a shape with the following Core Graphics code:

```
CGMutablePathRef pathRef = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(pathRef, NULL, 300, 300);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, NULL, 400, 300);
CGPathAddCurveToPoint(pathRef, NULL, 400, 335.727, 380.94, 368.739, 350, 386.603);
CGPathCloseSubpath(pathRef);

CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 1, 1, 1, 1);
CGContextAddPath(ctx, pathRef);
CGContextFillPath(ctx);

CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 1);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, 0, 0, 0, 1);
CGContextAddPath(ctx, pathRef);
CGContextStrokePath(ctx);

CGPathRelease(pathRef);
```

I notice when I add it to a SKShapeNode, it looses it's fill and stroke color. I also notice when I scale this object, it treats it like a SpriteNode, and not a vector.

I know you can adjust the SKShapeNode's stroke, fill, stroke width, lineCap, and other things.

I would like the best of both worlds. How could I get the complete shape, with fills, and strokes from CoreGraphics into a SKNode so I can translate it and receive mouse click events?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Graphics properties are ignored, only those on the shape node are applied.

SKShapeNode essentially just renders the path onto a texture, henceforth the shape node is no different than a sprite.

This is just how it is. Trading some features for better rendering performance.

Comment: Um, ok, but there has to be a way to get a Core Graphic image onto a node or some other kind of view.

Comment: That has been done before, I believe. Ie render Core Graphics to UIImage, then use the UIImage to create a texture/sprite with it. What you can hardly do is to update that image every frame, that would simply slow down things too much. You can also use shaders if you target iOS 8.0+ devices.